# Awesomewm: How to make a not-focusable client (google-chrome in Ubuntu) in default focusable?

Tags: awesome-wm

I want to make Google chrome focusable while using awesomeWM in Ubuntu 18.04. How can I do it?

I'm new to use awesomeWM as a window manager in Ubuntu 18.04, and I prefer Google chrome (not chromium, because my password manager don't work). I installed Chrome as a `.deb` package in [official](https://www.google.com/chrome/).

However, in default, Chrome spawned by `<mod> + r` and `google-chrome` cannot be focused by `<mod> + space` and don't obey to layouts.

Besides I found `google-chrome`'s `WM_CLASS` is `Google-chrome` by `xwininfo` and `xprop` and refered to the [doc](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/client.html#client.focusable), I added this code in my `rc.lua`:

```lua
    { rule = { class = "Google-chrome" },
      properties = { focusable = true }
    },
```

And reboot. I expect this code enables `google-chrome` focusable, but it was still not focusable.

How do I correct the code?

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that the window is not focusable or that it cannot be tiled? Based on your description, I wonder if Chrome is defaulting to a maximized state. If you're able, try pressing `<mod> + m` to unmaximize the client. If that works, add `maximized_vertical = false` and `maximized_horizontal = false` to the rule:

```
    { rule = { class = "Google-chrome" },
      properties = { focusable = true, 
                     maximized_vertical = false, 
                     maximized_horizontal = false }
    },
```